# How to ensure a child component calls parent function after Ember.run.later is completed in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, parent-child, ember-components

In a parent component, I have the following:

```
.
.
.
recurringFunc: function(delay, index){
  .
  .
  .
  if (someFlag){
    Ember.run.later(_this, function() {
      _this.send('otherFunc',{index: index});
      _this.send('recurringFunc', delay, ++index);
    }, delay);
  }
},


otherFunc: function(somePara){
  .
  .
  .
}
```

In parent template I have the following:

```
.
.
.
{{template-name someFlag=someFlag}}
.
.
.
```

Then in the child componoent I have the following:

```
input: function(){
  this.set('someFlag', false);
  this.sendAction('otherFunc', {index: someVal});
}
```

When the action if fired from the child component, it successfully, changes someFlag in the parent.  But the code does not wait for the last `Ember.run.later` iteration in the parent to run, before it executes the otherFunc call that was initiated from the child.

I have other code that I have abbreviated that is dependent on the otherFunc running after the last iteration of Ember.run.later.

How do I call a parent component function from a child component and ensure the Ember.run.later is finished before the child function called is executed?

Comment: What does this have to do with async-await? Are you even using ES8? Which of the functions return promises?

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought the async-await meant something else.  I will remove that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this problem, this is what I did.

I made `delay` a property on the parent component and updated `otherFunc` in the parent component as follows:

```
otherFunc: function(somePara){
  var currentDelay = this.get('delay');
  Ember.run.later(_this, function() {
    .
    .
    .
    .
  }, currentDelay);
}
```

This will call the new instructions after the last delay is finished from `recurringFunc`.